# Variant of \quark_if_novalue:n not generating

Tags: expl3

I have a token list variable, which I assigned by extracting a key from a property list. I now want to test if the token list is the `\q_novalue` quark.
From what I understand, I would need the `\tl_if_novalue:VTF` variant for this, which I wanted to generate by

```
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \quark_if_novalue:n { V } { T, F, TF }
```

But this results in the control sequence not being defined, see the below test document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \quark_if_novalue:n { V } { T, F, TF }
  \quark_if_no_value:VTF \l_tmpa_tl{}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff
  
\end{document}
```

So I wanted to ask what I am doing wrong here / how to properly test if the token list variable contains the `\q_novalue` quark.

Comment: Please, fix the function names in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, token list variables are set to `\q_no_value`, for instance when `\prop_get:NnN` is applied with a nonexistent key.

The correct conditional to use for this case is `\quark_if_no_value:NTF`

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_put:Nnn \l_tmpa_prop { a } { valueA }

\prop_get:NnN \l_tmpa_prop { a } \l_tmpa_tl

\quark_if_no_value:NTF \l_tmpa_tl {\iow_term:n {QUARK}}{\iow_term:n {NOT~QUARK}}

\prop_get:NnN \l_tmpa_prop { b } \l_tmpa_tl

\quark_if_no_value:NTF \l_tmpa_tl {\iow_term:n {QUARK}}{\iow_term:n {NOT~QUARK}}

\stop
```

The output on the terminal is

```
NOT QUARK
QUARK
```